# How to receive data from HID device in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, io, hid

I'm currently working on the Unity software that connects to a microcontroller. The MC connects via USB HID to the computer and sends sensor data in hopes that it will be displayed in the Unity software. I've tried reading the Unity Input System documentation but it mostly describes devices like mouse, gamepad, stick, etc. Maybe someone who understands this can provide an answer. Thank you!

Comment: You say the device acts as a USB HID, but does it emulate some kind of device the Unity input system supports? If not, you may need to use a USB library instead of Unity's input system.

Comment: The documentation said that we can add our custom device to the Unity input system, and I'm taking that approach cause I guess it will be easier. I've managed to get my device detected, but the received data isn't correct yet.

Comment: If you have implemented something already, and you're looking for help debugging. Please attach the relevant parts of your code to your question.